# What kind of optimization problem is $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAy$

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an arbitrary vector.

What type of optimization question is

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}x^TAy$$

where we seek to minimize $x$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$. I know it is not a QP. Is it just a linear program? The fact we have an $A$ matrix makes me uncertain

What are the conditions for convexity?

Comment: Is $f$ not linear in $x$?

Comment: Yes, it's a linear program

Comment: Note that as any linear transformation can be represented just as multiplication with matrix, than $Ay$ is just some linear transformation of $y$. Or simplier its just another vector. So $f$ is just a scalar product of two vectors. So yes, it is linear programming. For convexity (if I understand you correctly) conditions, you should take $x$ from some subset, but you haven't mentioned anything about it.

Comment: This is a linear problem. Without any constraints, it's a "void" problem as it's infimums is $-\infty$. With some constraints, things can become a bit more interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a convex and linear optimization problem. It is solvable if and only if $Ay=0$.